# IE6 li display on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

i am well aware of iE6 hover probs and workarounds. what i am failing to see is how to show a li on hover in IE6? for example there is a link for support and when hovered over i would like a ul li to appear and on hover out just show initial link. any tips to get me started? many thanks

html code example

http://jsfiddle.net/zdUMG/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one thing, your HTML is invalid.

You need to wrap the whole thing in a `ul`, and you need to move the submenu `ul` inside the `li`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zdUMG/2/

Then, you need some simple CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/zdUMG/3/

```
#nav li ul {
    display: none
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block
}
```

But, that won't work in IE6.

> i am well aware of iE6 hover probs and
>   workarounds

So, what's the problem?

Just use [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html) to allow a selector like `#nav li:hover ul` to work in IE6.

Comment: @thirtydot whatever:hover dosen't seem to work for me. i only at this point need to know the html and css code to display links on hover.

Comment: when i go to click links from li the list goes back to support. how do i css so links are clickable. thanks

Comment: That doesn't happen with my demo. I need to see what you have to tell you how to fix it. By the way, if Whatever:hover isn't working for you, I recommend this tutorial: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/. I recommend it anyway, it is of high quality.

Comment: @thirtydot it is not a menu as such just a list of links i want to produce when a user hovers over support. thanks for the link. i have updated fiddle with html and css. thanks http://jsfiddle.net/zdUMG/4/

Comment: I just tested that locally using IE6 by copying the source code of this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zdUMG/5/show/light/ and placing it in a HTML file in the same folder as `csshover3.htc`. The hover works and I can click the links. I'm not sure what you want me to fix?

Comment: do i have to modify the htc file? ok i have accepted your initial answer and need to see if there is something in my css that is stopping it working. thanks

Comment: No, **do not** modify the `.htc` file. As long as the `.htc` file is in the same folder as your `.html` file, it will just work. Here's a `.zip` of what I tested to work in IE6 before: http://www.2shared.com/file/Rr9TDRh3/bollo.html

Comment: @thirtydot thank you very much. and the htc file is just a beahvior file right?

Comment: Yes[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533336/ie6-li-display-on-hover/6533470#6533470)

Comment: thank you. will try to get to the bottom of why this list dissapears when i move an entry